# dominion adventures, using tokens on duration piles

Tags: dominion, dominion-adventures

If a token from Dominion Adventures is placed on a duration pile, is the token applied only when you initially play (lay down) the duration card or both when you lay it down AND when you play the duration effects at the start of the next turn? The directions say "when a player... plays a card".  For duration cards, is the second use "playing" it again?
Makes a difference on whether I'd ever put a token on Hireling or not!

Answer (score 9):

You only "play" the Duration once, on the turn when you, well, play it. The next turn it will just have an effect without you needing to play it.

So this means Durations don't work especially well with the +1 Card etc tokens. They'll still work okay, especially if your deck is reasonably big (so you don't often have Durations enduring over the reshuffle).

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that might be the case, but it was worth an ask.

Comment: Note that this is also why Durations in play from the previous turn don't count towards Conspirator's checking how many actions have been played. But they DO count towards Peddler checking how many cards are "in play."